# Function parameter in recursive async fn

Tags: rust, async-await

In Rust it is possible to have function parameters in asynchronous functions:

```
use futures::executor::block_on;

async fn hello_world(cb: &dyn Fn() -> u32) {
    println!("hello, world! {}", cb());
}

fn main() {
    let future = hello_world(&|| { 42 } );
    block_on(future);
}
```

But one limitation of these asynchronous functions is they cannot be recursive. The literature recommends using things like `BoxFuture` to work around the problem. But the simple transformation that is documented does not work if there is a function parameter:

```
use futures::executor::block_on;
use futures::future::{BoxFuture, FutureExt};

fn hello_world(cb: &dyn Fn() -> u32) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()> {
    async move {
        println!("hello, world! {}", cb());
    }.boxed()
}

fn main() {
    let future = hello_world(&|| { 42 } );
    block_on(future);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> u32` cannot be shared between threads safely
 --> src/main.rs:7:7
  |
7 |     }.boxed()
  |       ^^^^^ `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> u32` cannot be shared between threads safely
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `dyn std::ops::Fn() -> u32`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> u32`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/main.rs:5:16: 7:6 cb:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> u32 _]`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `std::future::from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:5:16: 7:6 cb:&dyn std::ops::Fn() -> u32 _]>`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Why did the transformation with `BoxFuture` cause a compilation error?
How to have a function parameter in a recursive asynchronous function?

I have tried using `LocalBoxFuture` instead of `BoxFuture` but the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to further constrain the function passed to `hello_world` - ensuring that it is both `Send` and `Sync` so it can safely be shared between threads.

I haven't done a lot of work with futures or async Rust - so I'm not completely over the details. But based on the error messages I was able to make your example compile by simply adding those constraints and letting Rust infer a lifetime instead of using `'static`:

```rust
use futures::executor::block_on;
use futures::future::{BoxFuture, FutureExt};

fn hello_world<F: Send + Sync + Fn() -> u32>(cb: &F) -> BoxFuture<'_, ()> {
    async move {
        println!("hello, world! {}", cb());
    }
    .boxed()
}

fn main() {
    let future = hello_world(&|| 42);
    block_on(future);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=48f9ac5edee5dbc66ed6e01acd38e399)

Answer (score 0):

I also found this crate https://github.com/dcchut/async-recursion which worked for me.